# How to group dates into years, when the year starts on a month other than January

Tags: r

I have this data containing dates from 2000 to 2020:

```
date[1:5]
# [1] "2000-01-01" "2000-01-02" "2000-01-03" "2000-01-04" "2000-01-05" 

str(date)
# Date[1:941], format: 2000-01-01" "2000-01-02" "2000-01-03" "2000-01-04"..
```

I can do this:

```
indices <- cut(date, "year")
```

Then all dates from `"2000-01-01"` to `"2000-12-31"` will be mapped to `"2000-01-01"`.

But I want all dates from `"1999-12-01"` to `"2000-11-30"` to be mapped to `"2000-01-01"`.

I want the equivalent of `cut(date, "year")`, but where the year is shifted to start on a month other than January.

How can I do this?

Comment: Can you give an example of your desired output, in code? It's not clear to me what you are looking for.

Comment: I think I was able to figure it out. I have edited your question, please take a look and make sure it is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of solving this problem is defining a sequence of desired breaks and the associated labels.  Such as this:

```
date<-as.Date(c("2000-01-01", "2000-01-02", "2000-01-03", "2000-01-04", "2000-01-05"))

#define break points
cutpoints<-seq.Date(as.Date("1999-12-01"), by="1 year", length.out = 23)
#define labels (1 less than the number of breaks)
names<-seq.Date(as.Date("2000-01-01"), by="1 year", length.out = 22)


cut(date, breaks=cutpoints, labels = names)
```